# How can I call a div to place under another div at the same html?

Tags: jquery, html, call, nested

I need to call a **div** by its *class*, to be placed under another **div**. 
Both divs are at the same html (but I want to have them separated for some reasons).

For example I have something like this:

```
<div class="apple">

</div>
.
.
.
<div class="container">
I need to call "apple" to be here.
</div>
```

I know I can just put "apple" inside "container" since they both are at the same html, but in my case I want them to be separated.

Comment: Are you wanting to move the `.apple` element to a child of `.container`?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? Are you asking how to query the DOM for HTML elements in JavaScript (`document.getElementsByClassName('apple')[0]`) or jQuery (`$('.apple')`)?

Comment: What do you mean by "under"? Appended as a child-node in the DOM tree, or positioned at a greater distance from the top of the document/viewport/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this : on page load, `apple` div get added to `container` div using [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```
$(function(){
    $('.apple').appendTo('.container');
   });
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can have the divs that I called (lets say I have 20 different divs called apple), into the container RANDOMLY? So they wont be in order right after another.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript function onclick and document.getElementByID('idname ').classname="apple";

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(".apple").detach().appendTo(".container");
```

Answer (score 0):

your jquery

```
$('.container').append($('.apple').html());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/haxBT/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *appendTo()* or *append()* method.
You can see the code here http://codepen.io/agus-pd/pen/JqBGD

```
$(".apple").appendTo(".container");
```

in this example I use appendTo method.